# Stylesheets in Rails App are incorrectly scoped

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, ruby-2.0

I have my main application css and I want to exclude my backend stylesheets since the styles all bleed over when application.css executed `*=require_tree .`

I currently have my folders setup like so:

```
assets/   
   stylesheets/
       main/ #application.css ##other css files for front end
       backend/ #backend.css ##other css files for back end
```

My application.css is as follows:

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require foundation_and_overrides
*= require_tree ./main/
*/
```

backend.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require_tree ./backend/
 */
```

in my application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += ['application.css', 'backend.css']
```

my development.rb

```
 config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
```

I tried moving the stylesheets around and playing with different directories, but I would either have the stylesheet not load at all or would receive "could not find foundation_and_overrides"...

Is there an easy clean way to do this? **I just want to exclude a couple stylesheets from being compiled with application.css**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of sprockets is that you include what you need. You can always add another stylesheet to the page as a whole. It's good practice to compile into one with users, but if backend is used by administrators, adding another stylesheet is totally fine.

First off, `application.css` is already precompiled, so you just need:

```
config.assets.precompile << 'backend.css'
```

Optionally include an additional stylesheet, so `application.css` has foundation, etc and `backend.css` has just additional styling:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: :all %> 
<% if admin? %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'backend', media: :all %> 
<% end %>
```

You can also add a `shared` directory for stylesheets that are for both if for some reason the `application.css` styles would conflict with the `backend.css` styles.

```
+ stylesheets
  + shared
  + app
  + backend
  - application.css
  - backend.css
```

And `require_tree ./shared` in both.